# How to write overwrite custom javascript for save button in quick create form

Tags: sugarcrm

I want to do some validation for my custom quick create form.

I have added some `JS` code in full form. its working fine in full form.
but same thing is not working in quick form.

```
'customCode' => '<input title="Save [Alt+S]" accessKey="S" class="button" onclick="this.form.action.value=\'Save\'; return test();" type="submit" name="button" value="Save">'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To customize subpanel buttons.**

Suppose we need to hide Create and Select buttons, or if we need to navigate quick create to full form. Then we need to follow following steps.

We need to first see the Subpanel's name.(which you can find out from studio/module/Relationships).

Navigate to custom/Extension/modules/Parent_Module/Ext/Layoutdefs

create one file like custombysachin.php.

and code like this.

```
<?php
$layout_defs["parent_module"]["subpanel_setup"]["subpanel_name"]['top_buttons']= array (
    0 =>
    array (
      'widget_class' => 'SubPanelTopCreateButton',
    ),   

 // 1 =>
    // array (
      // 'widget_class' => 'SubPanelTopSelectButton',
      // 'mode' => 'MultiSelect',
    // ),

  );
?>
```

Comment: Hi Bro, As you said I followed samething but no luck. how we can redirect create button to full form page.

Comment: I have tried again... its working fine... Thanks a lot

Comment: IF you find my comments useful then dont forget to mark it as useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi You need to add same js file into related module. If you are looking to changes Accounts subpanel in Contacts module then your code will be as

File Path:    `custom/module/Accounts/metadata/quickcreatedefs.php`

```
<?php
$viewdefs ['Accounts'] = 
array (
  'QuickCreate' => 
  array (
    'templateMeta' => 
    array (         
      'maxColumns' => '2',     
      'includes' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'file' => '{path-to-js-file}',
        ),
      ),
      'useTabs' => false,
    ),       
  ),
);
?>
```

Comment: I have already added javascript .. but save button needs to be trigger. but the custom save button is not working...  actually I have written some js function when I click on save button It shows the javascript popup mes.

Comment: how to overwrite custom code for save button in quickcreatedefs.php ?